# Get value from automatic generated select with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I made a treelist of data, in this treelist I'm trying to edit some data that's stored inside a select through a JSON post to the edit action. For this I need to get the value out of this select with jquery, me and some colleges tried everything but we can't get this thing working.

The treelist is generated through a foreach and when a submit butten is clicked the function with the ID is called and jquery should get the selected value.

```
function Edit_hpg(id) {
    var select = '#select1.1.' + id;
    select = $(select + "option:selected").each();
    $.getJSON('/PrijsCodeKoppeling/HoofdProductGroep', {
        id: (id),
        prijscode: $(select)
    }, function (data) {
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the DOM elements to server in your Ajax call.

Try this:

```
function Edit_hpg(id) {
    var select = '#select1.1.' + id;
    var selectedItems = new Array(); 
    $(select + " option:selected").each(function(index, elem){
          selectedItems.push($(elem).val());
    });
    $.getJSON('/PrijsCodeKoppeling/HoofdProductGroep', {
        id: (id),
        prijscode: selectedItems
    }, function (data) {
    })
}
```

On the server, you will get an Array of selected Items.

Comment: I alerted the results before the JSON post, unfortunately I got an empty result.

Comment: Mmm... kinda weird, the value of the data I want to edit is 11, but I really get back just an empty alert.. He didn't reach the breakpoint at the begin of the action in the controller neither. Can't get through the JSON post with empty results, so I'm sure it's empty..

Comment: Try to copy the code again from my answer. There was space missing in it (between select +"option...) there is suppose to be a space after double quotes and before the word "option".

Comment: Still no result.. In alert the selectedItems array is just existing and empty.. ;(

Comment: try alert($(select + " option:selected").length) and see if the selector is working fine or not. if you get 0 then the selector is not right

Comment: Thanks for all the help UmairP, I've solved it, apparently jquery doesn't handle the id "select" well, I tried it with a different name and now it works.